# Standard Colors for Syntax Highlighting

Tags: syntax-highlighting, color-scheme

I am working on customizing my vim syntax highlighting (see [here](https://github.com/johndgiese/dotvim/blob/master/colors/betterblack.vim) for what I have so far), and I was wondering: **Are there any sort of syntax color standards?**  For example, are strings always red, and comments orange?  If anyone knows of such a standard, or even has suggestions for particular syntax groups, that would be great!  Hex codes would be even better!

Comment: I am actually interested in the answer to that question.

Comment: I wish this question would be re-opened. Is there any way we could edit this to make it valid?